# If another request is running a method wait until finish

Tags: c#, asp.net, concurrency

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web API application with C#, .NET Framework 4.7 and MongoDb.

I have this method:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/Public/SendCommissioning/{serial}/{withChildren}")]
public HttpResponseMessage SendCommissioning(string serial, bool withChildren)
{
    string errorMsg = "Cannot set commissioning.";

    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    bool serverFound = true;

    try
    {
        [...]
        // Mongo
        MongoHelper mgHelper = new MongoHelper();
        mgHelper.InsertCommissioning(serial, withChildren);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error(ex.Message);

        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        response.ReasonPhrase = errorMsg;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Sometimes this method is called very quickly and I get an error here:

```
// Mongo
MongoHelper mgHelper = new MongoHelper();
mgHelper.InsertCommissioning(serial, withChildren);
```

Here I'm inserting the serials I received in order, and sometimes I get an error with a duplicated key in MongoDb:

I have a method to get the latest id used in Mongo (the primary key). And two requests get the same id, so when I try to insert it on Mongo I get an invalid key exception.

I thought to use a queue to store the serials and then consume them in the same order that I have received them. But I think I will get the same error when I try to store the serial in MongoDb.

Maybe if I can set a method that if it is running, I have to wait to run it, it will works. This method will have the part of insert the serials into Mongo.

How can I do that? A method that if it is running you can't run it in another Web Api request.

Or, do you know a better option?

By the way, I can't block this method. Maybe I need to run a thread with this synchronized part.

Comment: Use a singleton that handles the requests sequentially. Or add a wrapper to the mongohelper that uses some form of synchronization to add your desires behaviour.

Comment: Isn't this just a design flaw? You expect serial to be unique but it isn't? If this is on the same instance you could lock on a static object inside `InsertCommisioning`.

Comment: @rene I have a method to get the latest id used in Mongo (the primary key). And two requests get the same id, so when I try to insert it on Mongo I get an invalid key exception.

Comment: Well, just don't get an latest id. Just have the client provide their new data, Insert into Mongo and tell the client which key that new data just got. problem solved without all the hassle. Databases are extremely good at generating unique id's under high load ...

Comment: But i need to insert the serial in the same order that I have received. If I let the method to insert a serial before another serial that I have received before it is an error. This is why I want to use the queue.